# Generating OpenCover Reports Using TFS 2015 Build Preview

Tags: powershell, tfs, nunit, opencover, tfs-2015

I'm using the following code to generate a coverage report from a powershell script task in TFS 2015's Build Preview. I can run it on the build server and it generates the report correctly, but when it runs as part of the build it complains that there are no pdb files.

> No results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common
>   reasons are:
>
> 1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
>
> 2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage guide and the -register switch.

After doing a bit of Googling I discovered that /noshadow should have been enough, but it seems that the parameters for nunit are getting ignored. I'm assuming they're being ignored because the /nologo command should be stripping out the copyright info from being printed, but in the console output I can still see the information being displayed.

Also using the build output directory as the working directory should have fixed this as well, but using Set-Location didn't resolve the problem during the build.

This is the script that I'm currently running:

```
Param
(
    [string] $SourceDir = $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY,
    [string] $UnitTestDir = "",
    [string] $UnitTestDll ="",
    [string] $Filter = "",
    [string] $ExcludeByAttribute = "System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute",
    [string] $nUnitOutputPath = "Output.txt",
    [string] $nUnitErrorOutputPath = "Error.text",
    [string] $XmlOutputPath = "_CodeCoverageResult.xml",
    [string] $ReportOutputPath = "_CodeCoverageReport"
)

$openCoverPath = "E:\BuildTools\OpenCover.4.5.3723\OpenCover.Console.exe"
$nUnitPath = "E:\BuildTools\NUnit.Runners.2.6.4\tools\nunit-console.exe"
$reportGeneratorPath = "E:\BuildTools\ReportGenerator.2.1.1.0\ReportGenerator.exe"

$nUnitArgs = "$SourceDir\$UnitTestDir\$UnitTestDll /noshadow /nologo"

Write-Host "[Debug] Setting location to $SourceDir\$UnitTestDir"
Set-Location $SourceDir\$UnitTestDir

if (!(Test-Path $SourceDir\CodeCoverage)) {
    New-Item $SourceDir\CodeCoverage -type directory
}
Write-Host "[Debug] Running unit tests from $SourceDir\$UnitTestDir\$UnitTestDll" 
Write-Host "[Debug] Command: $openCoverPath -target:$nUnitPath -targetargs:""$nUnitArgs"" -filter:$Filter -excludebyattribute:$ExcludeByAttribute -register:user -output:""$SourceDir\CodeCoverage\$XmlOutputPath"""

& $openCoverPath -target:$nUnitPath -targetargs:"$nUnitArgs" -filter:$Filter -excludebyattribute:$ExcludeByAttribute -register:user -output:"$SourceDir\CodeCoverage\$XmlOutputPath"

Write-Host "[Debug] Generating report"
Write-Host "[Debug] Command: $reportGeneratorPath ""-reports:$SourceDir\CodeCoverage\$XmlOutputPath"" ""-targetdir:$SourceDir\CodeCoverage\$ReportOutputPath"""

& $reportGeneratorPath -reports:$SourceDir\CodeCoverage\$XmlOutputPath -targetdir:$SourceDir\CodeCoverage\$ReportOutputPath

Write-Host "[Debug] Finished running tests and generating report"
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to wrap your nunit args in quotes using `"

```
& $openCoverPath -target:$nUnitPath -targetargs:"`"$nUnitArgs`"" -filter:$Filter -excludebyattribute:$ExcludeByAttribute -register:user -output:"$SourceDir\CodeCoverage\$XmlOutputPath"
```

There is a fix in [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover/commit/95495b76e1f8f06d8128f46dbaa2152d68a9cb93) for the next release which will detect when you are passing unrecognized arguments to OpenCover